# How to handle events in custom form control without inputText

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, form-control

I'm trying to create a custom form control, a list picker in screen (no modal or native ios picker). The custom control does not include any TextInput o Picker control. How to handle the state change and update the form state?

I'm using Formik. In formik I need use handleChange event to update the form values and validate data, but I don't know how to call that.

```
class ProfileForm extends Component {

  state = {
    selectedPaymentMethod: this.props.paymentMethod
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <Fragment>
        <TextInput
          value={this.props.values.name}
          onChangeText={this.props.handleChange('name')} // it works
        <List.Item // a list picker item
          title="Card"
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({ selectedPaymentMethod: 0 }); 
            this.props.handleChange('paymentMethod', 1)}; // it don't
          } />
        <List.Item // another list picker item
          title="Cash"
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({ selectedPaymentMethod: 1 }); 
            this.props.handleChange('paymentMethod', 0)}; // it don't
          } />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The main idea is to make clic on list item picker and call formik handleChange event.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used formik, but I don't think you should be executing a function in the onChangeText prop in any case. You should only pass a reference.

```
onChangeText={() => this.props.handleChange('name')}
```

Comment: Hi @paruchuri-p thanks for you answer 
I'm using a list component without onChangeText event, Formik makes me call handleChange event

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it finally.
Formik has setFieldValue method (https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean-void) 
I called this in my onPress method and it works.